# UNITY how to pass data from variable from two non-intersecting scenes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to pass a data (string) to another scene in Unity. The problem is that these two scenes don't intersect with each other, meaning if you choose the first scene, even though I put DontDestroyOnLoad() to the script I want to fetch from, it will be useless because I won't be on the second scene where I want to fetch the data to anymore. It's either go to THIS scene or go to THAT scene. They don't know each other. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your first scene, you can put a PlayerPrefs and it's very easy

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("StringName", stringToPass);
```

With this line, you are saving your string (stringToPass) permanently even if you close the game as the name of "StringName"

In the new scene you can then call it as

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("StringName", "noString");
```

With this you are calling the string you saved in the "StringName" and, if you haven't ever put a string inside it it will return "noString";

You can save it to a new string also

```
newString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("StringName", "emptyString");
```

Comment: I can't use PlayerPrefs because in my case, my game should not have a default value because it depends on whenver someone creates a room (Photon). It does not hold data when the project has been built. It just does it locally

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1221717/playerprefs-not-working-on-android-2.html

check this out

Comment: @VirtualDreamer then you can set the defaul value as the room creation value. And reset it every time so it is not storing. You can also use static strings for this